# Combine Scope with current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have a scope like this :

```
class InventoryItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :inventory
  belongs_to :game_item

  # define custom scopes to get equipped inventory items for user
  scope :equipped, where(:is_equipped => 1)

  scope :item, lambda { |item_type|
    joins(:game_item).
    includes(:game_item).
    where("game_items.item_type = ?", item_type ).
    limit(1)
  }
```

can i get the current_user model that also includes equipped items in one command ? (with includes maybe ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your inventory belongs to a user, you could include the current_user model using this:

```
scope :equipped, where(:is_equipped => 1).includes(:inventory => :user)
```

This tells Rails to include the inventory model and the associated user model for that inventory.  If you wanted to do the same for the item scope you could do this:

```
scope :item, lambda { |item_type|
  includes(:game_item).
  includes(:inventory => :user).
  where("game_items.item_type = ?", item_type ).
  limit(1) }
```